# Having trouble getting flex list items to match child size

Tags: html, css

I've created a `ul` set as flex, with links inside with a padding. However, the `li`s containing them seem to match the width, but not the height of their children. I'm not sure how to do this, or if I have to manually set the height for it?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As in the code, the `li` in red doesn't match the interior `a` in green.

Comment: Add `a{display: inline-block;}`

Comment: Just inherit the flexible declaration for li tag.